# Вывод выбранных строк с новой строки

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть php код. Он работает неправильно, выводит только одно максимальное значение, а мне нужно чтобы он вывел 3 максимальных значения с новой строки каждое. Буду признателен за коррекцию кода.

```
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $user="admin";
    $pass="root";
    $db_name="game";
    $link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `nickname`, `gold` FROM `users` ORDER BY `gold` DESC LIMIT 3");
    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    foreach ($rows as $value)
    {
        echo "$value";
    }
?>
```

Comment: mysql  пора забыть уже ... только pdo или mysqli

Comment: А если вывести дамп $rows - что показывает? В таблице users действительно есть больше 1 пользователя?